# SQL Sum of Counts and Group By

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
ID  Status
--  -------
1   OK
2   OK
3   NOTOK
4   NOTOK
5   OK
```

I want to do a count and **group by status** and also have the sum of the count on each row. The count works but I do not know how to do the sum to appear on each row like this:

```
Status     Count   TotalCount
-------  -----  ------
OK        3       5
NOTOK     2       5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Status, count(*) occurrences, count(*) over(partition by Status) total_count from table group by Status
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, SUM(*) AS Sum FROM *your table* GROUP BY Status`.
You can use AS to rename whatever you want. I think sum will appear now.

Comment: not giving arguments for sum apparently throws an error, also this doesn't group them by status as I mentioned in bold above

Comment: My bad, I did not read correctly. Then this can be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two windowed counts:

```
select distinct status, 
    Count(*) over(partition by status) as "count", 
    Count(*) over() as "Sum"
from t;
```

without window functions you could take various approaches, one would be

```
with c as (
    select  status, Count(*) as "Count"
    from t
    group by status
)
select *, (select Sum("count") from c) as "Sum"
from c
```

And in case CTE's are not supported...

```
select *, (select Count(*) from t) as "Sum"
from (
    select  status, Count(*) as "Count"
    from t
    group by status
)c
```

Comment: I want to do the query without window functions as this db doesn't support them (only difference from sql,the rest are supported)

Comment: @AndrrAndrr you only tagged *SQL* which implies standard ANSI SQL, which does include window functions - you should [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your specific RDBMS

Comment: Yes, sorry the RDBMS is specific to a system I work in and is not so known, I wanted to edit the question right after posting it in order to say without partition but it did not let me edit it as it said "the modification should be substantial", but if you could give me a solution without partition I'd highly appreciate it

Comment: @AndrrAndrr have edited my answer with another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery.

```
SELECT Status, COUNT(*) as Count, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table) AS TotalCount FROM my_table GROUP BY Status;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa9392/7)